# Returning a value from a subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscription

Having this code, I would like to return a string value from this subscription :

```
this.langPipe.transform(text).subscribe((res: any) => {
        return res['value']
    });
```

The transform langPipe function return a `Observable<string>`.

The fact is, this is of course not running and I don't understand who to do it with a map.
On my template, I just want to show it in a title attribute of a div.

This is probably a duplicate and I saw similar threads but i really don't understand how it works.

If anyone has an idea, it will be so much help. Thank in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscription are here to trigger an action, and give a callback when value are emitted or when observable finishes / raises an error. For instance, one could set a variable in the component class depending on the emitted values. But subscription is not supposed to return a value.

If you need this value to be returned, so you need a *transformation* of the emitted values, then you can use `map` operator instead of `subscribe`.

The result will be an `Observable<string>`, though, so if you are using this result elsewhere, you can pipe this with `async` pipe.

So instead of `{{ input | yourPipeReturningString }}`, you can use `{{ input yourPipeReturningObservble | async }}`

Basically, the `async` Angular pipe will just subscribe to the underlying observable and return the value emitted.

Comment: Sadly, I need to use this pipe in my component as I need to do some treatment. I don't use the pipe in my html. What I want is something like this `<div title="{{ tooltipMsg(reservation) }}">` . I tried to use a map but in that case how to parse it so I can retreive the "value" attribute from this ?

Comment: @NicolasS. To use the 'return value' of Observable.map, (which returns itself an observable) pipe the result with `async`, something like `{{ tooltipMsg(reservation) | async }}` (can't know for sure what will fit your situation exactly, as you have not given any [mcve], for instance using a Plunker).